# Android ChromeCast: Tapping on my MiniControllerFragment doesn't open the ExpandedControllerActivity

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have an app that has a MiniControllerFragment in the layout:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:castShowImageThumbnail="true"
        app:
        class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />
```

I also have an ExpandedControllerActivity subclass:

```
public class ExpandedControlsActivity extends ExpandedControllerActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.expanded_controller, menu);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The MiniController works.  When casting, the play/pause buttons work fine.  However, tapping on the MiniController does nothing. It is supposed to open the ExpandedController, but I don't see how my MiniController is supposed to know which Activity to start.  Is there additional code or something in the manifest I need to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you construct your CastOptions, using its [Builder](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastOptions.Builder.html#setCastMediaOptions(com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.CastMediaOptions)), you need to pass in a [CastMediaOption](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/CastMediaOptions). This latter class (CastMediaOption) can be constructed using its [Builder](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/CastMediaOptions.Builder), which takes the name of your expanded controller activity, by calling [setExpandedControllerActivityClassName](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/CastMediaOptions.Builder.html#setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(java.lang.String))().

Comment: I am putting meta data for CastOptionsProvider but still it says that "CastOptionsProvider is never used". Any idea ?

Comment: @bhaskar You might want to post a new question with the details of your case so others can respond to that.

Comment: I have added setExpandedControllerActivityClassName() also but still have no luck of getting ExpandedControllerActivity. Any idea?